# How to addclass to parent when click child menu in VUEjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When I click `sub menu` in the following template, how do I add an `active` class to the `<a>` of a sibling `<router-link>` (of `menu1` or `menu2`)?

```html
<ul class="depth1">
  <li class="m1">
    <router-link to="/introduce/Introduce" @click="selected = 1" :class="{ active: selected == 1 }"><span>menu1</span></router-link>
    <ul class="depth2 sm1">
      <li><router-link to="" @click="selected = 1">sub menu</router-link></li> 
      <li><router-link to="" @click="selected = 1">sub menu</router-link></li> 
      <li><router-link to="" @click="selected = 1">sub menu</router-link></li> 
    </ul>
  </li> 
   <li class="m2">
    <router-link to="/introduce/Introduce"  @click="selected = 2" :class="{ active: selected == 2 }"><span>menu2</span></router-link>
    <ul class="depth2 sm1">
      <li><router-link to="" @click="selected = 2">sub menu</router-link></li> 
      <li><router-link to="" @click="selected = 2">sub menu</router-link></li> 
      <li><router-link to="" @click="selected = 2">sub menu</router-link></li> 
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      selected: false, 
    };
  },
  methods: { 
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any parent 'a' element

Comment: @Ayudh The `<router-link>`'s root element is `<a>` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is close to working, but the `click` handler isn't called because it's not applied correctly.

To add a `click` handler to the root element of `<router-link>` (i.e., the `<a>` tag), use [`@click.native`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components):

```html
<router-link to="" @click.native="selected = 1">sub menu</router-link>
                         ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

but, why not use `vue-router`'s default behaviors (link automatically get active class when the target route is active) like the below demo shows

```js
const Home = {
  template: '<div><h2>Home</h2></div>'
}
const About = {
  template: '<div><h2>About</h2></div>'
}

const Users = {
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Users</h2>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
  `
}

const User = {
  template: '<div>{{ $route.params.username }}</div>'
}

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [{
      path: '/',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      component: About
    },
    {
      path: '/users',
      component: Users,
      children: [{
        path: ':username',
        name: 'user',
        component: User
      }]
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
a.router-link-active {
  color: #f66;
}

li.router-link-active a {
  color: #f66;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Active Links</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/">/</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/" exact>/ (exact match)</router-link>
    </li>

    <li>
      <router-link to="/users">/users</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/users" exact>/users (exact match)</router-link>
    </li>

    <li>
      <router-link to="/users/evan">/users/evan</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/users/evan#foo">/users/evan#foo</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{ path: '/users/evan', query: { foo: 'bar' }}">
        /users/evan?foo=bar
      </router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <!-- #635 -->
      <router-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { username: 'evan' }, query: { foo: 'bar' }}" exact>
        /users/evan?foo=bar (named view + exact match)
      </router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link :to="{ path: '/users/evan', query: { foo: 'bar', baz: 'qux' }}">
        /users/evan?foo=bar&baz=qux
      </router-link>
    </li>

    <li>
      <router-link to="/about">/about</router-link>
    </li>

    <router-link tag="li" to="/about">
      <a>/about (active class on outer element)</a>
    </router-link>
  </ul>
  <router-view class="view"></router-view>
</div>
```